# Angular 2: current route title

Tags: angular

I have in my app.component.html this code:

```
<div id="main-container" class="container">
    <div class="container center-block" style="width: 300px">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading text-center"><h4>*******</h4></div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                <router-outlet></router-outlet>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to show the current route name in *******.

What's the best way to have this in Angular 2?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/set-document-title.html

Answer (score 0):

### Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class TitleService {
  constructor(private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
  }
  getPageTitle(replace: string) {
    return this._activatedRoute.url.replace('blah', replace);
  }
}
```

### Component:

```
url: string;
constructor(private _titleService:TitleService) {
  this.title = _titleService.getPageTitle('ReplaceTXT');
}
```

Then in your template

```
<h4>{{url}}</h4>
```

Comment: The interpolation in h4 is outside the component. I resolved with a shared service that the child component set its title in ngOnInit, but I'm not sure it's the best approach.

Comment: Yeah you shouldn't need to use ngOnInit for that. Have updated answer. I'd do something like that.

Comment: What exactly do you want inside the <h4> ? (i.e what exactly are you interpolating) You mentioned Route name, The new Angular RC Router doesn't have Route names. Are you wanting to show the URL in the <h4>? Basically I was just trying to show how you could do it, you'll have to tweak the implementation a bit unless you provide a bit more detail :)